# why is composer not working centos symfony4

Tags: php, symfony, centos, composer-php

my English is very bad,
I have a problem at install project symfony4.4 in server centos7 , with php7.3 , not php7.4 
in windows is OK with php7.3
i run the command line

/opt/plesk/php/7.3/bin/php /usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/composer.phar install

i have this result 
[image]

and this is my composer.json

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "api-platform/api-pack": "^1.2",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.3",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.7",
        "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "^1.7",
        "lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle": "^2.6",
        "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^3.5",
        "symfony/console": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/form": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/serializer": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.4",
        "symfony/translation": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/validator": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "4.4.*",
        "vich/uploader-bundle": "^1.13"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "ocramius/proxy-manager": "2.2.3",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.14",
        "symfony/profiler-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "4.4.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "4.4.*"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this problem , update composer

```
php composer.phar self-update
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install the ocramius/package-versions v.1.1.3 before run your "composer.phar install" command.